Issues with browsersync on ddev / wordpress / gulp - local setup - Either works on root or on subdirectories
Setup:
I exposed the ports for browsersync according to another question on stackoverflow:
#ddev-generated
# Override the web container's standard HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE
# This is to expose the browsersync port.
services:
  web:
    expose:
      - '3000'
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILPIT_HTTP_PORT}:8025,3001:3000
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILPIT_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,3000:3000

and my gulp function looks like this:
function serve2(done) {
  server.init({
    open: false,
    proxy: {
      target: "localhost"
    },
    host: "web",
  });
  done();
  watch([themePath + 'assets/scss/*.scss',themePath + 'assets/scss/*.scss' ],buildStyles).on('change', server.reload);
  watch([themePath + '*.php',themePath + '**/*.php', themePath + '**/**/*.php']).on('change', server.reload);
}

export const serves2 = serve2;

That setup works with all subdirectories on "https://test.ddev.site:3000/subdir/" and the according live reload on changes. But As soon as I try to access the root "https://test.ddev.site:3000/" it redirects me to "https://test.ddev.site" and live reload won't work.
If I add the port 80 to the proxy "target: 'localhost:80'" then the site "https://test.ddev.site:3000/" works with live reload BUT the subdirectories redirect me to "https://localhost/subdirectory" which results in a 404.
I tried different proxy targets e.g. localhost, test.ddev.site, web, but the behaviour seems to be the same in all ocurrences with the only thing changing that the redirect of the root directory brings me to the "different" wrong site when using it with a port.
I could run 2 different gulp setups depending on what page I am currently working on but it really feels unsatisfying after so many hours I tried to get it working. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

This is an older way of working with frontend in DDEV, try a new approach using this Vite example https://ddev.com/blog/working-with-vite-in-ddev/

@stasadev I mean gulp is around for way longer than vite, that is true, and I also looked at the vite approach and in my opinion the simplicity from gulp as a task runner just seems better for my use-case of wordpress workflow.

I'm not asking to use vite instead of gulp, use the same approach with web_extra_exposed_ports instead of overriding HTTP_EXPOSE and HTTPS_EXPOSE

I would certainly start with the browsersync add-on, https://github.com/ddev/ddev-browsersync, if I were you. It gives you a well-maintained and very specific starting point, uses the easier web_extra_exposed_ports and may work out of the box for you.

@stasadev okay, then I misunderstood your hint at first. Sorry for that.
I did actually got it working without overwriting the ports via the "docker-compose.browsersync.yaml" file by just removing the browsersync.yaml file and adding the following lines to config.yaml.
web_extra_exposed_ports:
- name: browsersync
container_port: 3000
http_port: 2999
https_port: 3000
I can switch between both methods in a minute or so but the behaviour and my issue with the doc root and the subdirectories only working like described above sadly stays.

@rfay thanks for the input. I actually did look at that repo already and had my setup mostly adapted over from that solution. I think I use quite the same settings as they do in their plugin as far as I can tell. The reason I didn't use the plugin was that I have some gulp tasks I want to run before refreshing the browser.

You can fork it and adapt :)

@rfay i wouldn't see anything different in their approach, btw, they use the solution you linked actually uses "HTTP_EXPOSE" and "HTTPS_EXPOSE" and not "web_extra_exposed_ports". ;)

Ah, yeah, you can't use web_extra_exposed_ports on an alternate service (different container). Sorry for the misdirection. You need to use HTTPS_EXPOSE, etc for that.

Oh, I see you are using the web container, right? So your approach is completely different, and you can use web_extra_exposed_ports, completely different. Your setup doesn't look bad, but I don't see where you're running the browsersync process. I do recommend the supported ddev-browsersync, and if you have trouble an issue there will get you a good response from @tyler36 if you explain clearly.

I looked at the "https://ddev.com/blog/working-with-vite-in-ddev/" approach when setting up gulp. So gulp runs inside of the web container. that is right.
I will definitely give the browsersync plugin a go, but I also really want to understand what of the setup is wrong right now (quite new to docker stuff and eager to learn).
